# What to do with old 32 bit desktops

Tags: smart-home, linux, upcycling

So I have two old 32-bit desktops from the early 2000s (I think one had XP and the other win 95). I have since updated them to now obsolete versions of Ubuntu.  With everything now 64-bit and since they are not compatible with the newest OS (to include the latest of Ubuntu), any good homelab or IoT ideas for them, or is it time to finally recycle them?

Comment: You mah want to ask your favorite computer history museum if for any reason they would be interested. Other than that, just the power draw of such computers makes them a pretty uninteresting proposition IMHO. Not to mention their size and sometimes the noise they make.

Answer (score 1):

Given that those computers are a security risk and are less power efficient than say, 2015 computers that I can buy at a goodwill store for $50, I recycled mine a while ago. Also glad that I did not have to invest time into keeping them going.
Unless you have something specific that is of huge sentimental value with that machine, feel free to recycle. See: [Does it bring you joy ?](https://www.happier.com/blog/5-life-changing-lessons-the-konmari-decluttering-method-taught-me/)

If you want a small amount of computing power to do something, consider a raspberry Pi.